# Regexp matching all unicode characters except alphabetic characters

Tags: regex, unicode, grep

How do I grep a UTF-8 text file for lines containing any character outside ASCII, **except** a select few characters, eg. `[æÆøØåÅ]`?

So the following three lines:

```
ABC
ÆØÅ
ABC-ÆØÅ
```

Should yield:

```
ABC-ÆØÅ
```

Because the smiley is outside ASCII and does not belong to the extra ignored characters.

Comment: Not ASCII: `([^\x00-\x7F]+)`. There is also `([^[:ascii:]])` if implemented.

Comment: This statement will find the "ÆØÅ" line, which it shouldn't. Read the original post again.

Comment: `grep '[^ÆØÅ[:ascii:]]' file`

Comment: @Jan All of those are incorrect for Basic Regular Expressions, which is what POSIX `grep` uses. The parentheses and the plus sign are all superfluous in this context, so the easy fix is to just drop them.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` doesn't support UTF-8. Try Perl:

```
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -ne 'print if /[^\x00-\x7FæÆøØåÅ]/' [FILE...]
```

`-CSD` enables UTF-8 IO. `-Mutf8` enables UTF-8 in source code.

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep seems to support UTF-8. The following solves the problem on OS X.

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/grep
ggrep -P '[^\x00-\x7FæÆøØåÅ]' *.txt
```